# How to represent a vector as a linear combination of minimal number of other given vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I have 300'000 vectors from $\mathbb R^{20}$, (let's call this set $V$), and some other vector $x$. I want to find out, what is the minimal number of vectors from $V$, such as $x$ can be represented as their linear combination. Is there a good algorithm for that?

I understand, that I can just extract an $\mathbb R^{20}$ basis from $V$ and convert $x$ to that basis, but it is not interesting because then $x$ will be represented as combination of 20 vectors, instead of minimal number of vectors. May be $x$ can be constructed by just 2 vectors from $V$.

Why do I ask: $V$ is OEIS database, and I want to make a program that will tell if user's sequence is a linear combination of a few sequences from OEIS.

Comment: [Compressed sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing) comes to mind, where they search for sparse solutions to an underdetermined system, which seems to be what you want. I am no expert, however I remember the general problem to be rather nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks mlk! Wikipedia says that the problem I described is NP-complete, but it can be approximated using the L1 norm instead of L0.